# How to uniquely identify Date and Time selector in a scenario where more than one DateTime Pickers shows the same XPATH?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How to uniquely identify Date and Time selector in a scenario where more than one DateTime Pickers (StartDate and EndDate) shows the same XPATH?

For example,

XPath of Select Date in Start Date(UTC) :
/html/body/div[3]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBsHI.png)/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBsHI.png)/span[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBsHI.png)/div/input
XPath of Select Date in End Date(UTC) :
/html/body/div[3]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBsHI.png)/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBsHI.png)/span[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBsHI.png)/div/input

As you can see, both (Start Date  and  End Date) have same XPATH, but using these XPATH automation via selenium not feasible

snapshot of DateTime Pickers on the same webpage
[image]

How to uniquely identify these controls so that it can be automated via Selenium?

Comment: only one date time picker show up at one time, you can use this to identify the visible one.

Comment: you can find the element with a reference of label(start date). can you add the relevant HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Modern web applications modify the DOM a lot to achieve the desired experience. 
The actual XPath depends on the click path since the behavior influences the shape of the DOM. On the first click to the startDate, the XPath is
/html/body/div[*2*]/div[1]/div/div[1]/span[1]/div/input 
since the UI library will add the div when the input field is clicked. 
When the end Date input field is clicked, another div is created for the popover for end date. This will then be:
/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/span[1]/div/input

Answer (score 0):

Look for some attributes in DOM corresponding to date-picker element, which makes them unique. If there are such attributes available, you can use them to identify controls uniquely like this

```
/html/body/div[3]/div1/div/div1/span1/div/input[@attributeName='attributeValue']
```

In case, there is no unique attributes available and both the date picker control is available, then you can use index to get first and second element using

First element:

```
/html/body/div[3]/div1/div/div1/span1/div//input[1]
```

Second element

```
/html/body/div[3]/div1/div/div1/span1/div//input[2]
```